# Advection-diffusion equation in latex

Tags: equations

I'm having problems (errors) in writing the advection-diffusion equation in tex.

```
\[\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} -\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left[D_{x} \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} -u_{x} c\right]-\frac{\partial }{\partial y} \left[D_{y} \frac{\partial c}{\partial y} -u_{y} c\right]-\frac{\partial }{\partial z} \left[D_{z} \frac{\partial c}{\partial z} -u_{z} c\right]=F\left[c,t\right]\]
```

It should work out as
[image: advection equation in MS Equation]

Document splitted in various sections:

Main document

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\printnomenclature  %% Print the nomenclature   
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\include{Introduction/introduction}
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
\include{Chapter3/chapter3}   
\include{Chapter4/chapter4}
\include{Chapter5/chapter5}   
\include{Conclusions/conclusions}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % changes default name Bibliography to References
\bibliography{References/references} % References file
\backmatter % book mode only
\appendix
\include{Appendix1/appendix1}
\end{document}
```

The appendix document has nothing different from other sections really...but there are no problems in the other when I write equations...

Help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) @cmhughes, indeed, it gives the expected output even _without_ `amsmath`.

Comment: this code works for me (even without `amsmath`) could you specify what you want different?

Comment: You are right...strange, but inside the Appendix section (where it should be in the thesis) doesn't work :S

Comment: @user17653, please edit your question to include a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. This will make it much easier for us to help you. `:-)`

Comment: Ok, let me try to check out this better...because it is just in the Appendix section that the equation (every equation, not just the one above) doesn't work.

Comment: @PaulGessler, I've edited the question with the main document structure...the others are simple chapters and sections

Comment: @user17653 this is not a MWE. We do not have any of your included files, and the LoF, LoT, nomenclature, and friends should be removed (unless removing them causes the problem to go away). Please review my previous link and post a complete, self-contained document that exhibits the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @user17653 any chance for an MWE? We cannot help until we can see what is going wrong. `:-)`